# Converting a series of floats to int - some NaNs in list are causing an error 'cannot convert float NaN to integer'. How to skip NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large column of phone numbers in a pandas dataframe, and they're in float format: `3.52831E+11`. There are also NaNs present.

I am trying to convert the numbers to int and it's throwing an error that NaNs can't be converted to int. Fair enough. But I can't seem to get around this.

Here's a sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number':['3.578724e+11','3.568376e+11','3.538884e+11',np.NaN]})


    number
0   3.578724e+11
1   3.568376e+11
2   3.538884e+11
3   NaN


# My first attempt: here's where I try to convert them to int() however I get 'cannot convert float NaN to integer'. 

df['number'] = [int(x) for x in df['number'] if isinstance(x, float)]


# I have also tried the below, but I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

df['number'] = [int(x) for x in df['number'] if x not None]


# and then this one, but the error is: TypeError: must be real number, not str

df['number'] = [int(x) for x in df['number'] if not math.isnan(x) and isinstance(x, float)]
```

I'd appreciate some pointers on this. I thought at least one of these would work.

Thanks folks

Comment: How about 'if x' ?

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df.number,errors='coerce').dropna().astype(int)` ??

Comment: Just follow the first answer on the Dupe

Comment: @SCool what is your pandas version?

Comment: @cs95 pandas==0.24.1

Comment: OK, I'm going to reopen this because the solution is a little more nuanced than presented in the dupe.

Comment: @anky_91 this is the result. Still a float: `0        -2.147484e+09
1        -2.147484e+09
2        -2.147484e+09
3        -2.147484e+09
4        -2.147484e+09`

Comment: @BlueRineS `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.578724e+11'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pandas 0.24+, we have the [Nullable Integer Type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type). The first step is to convert your strings (objects) to float, then to nullable int:

```
df.astype('float').astype(pd.Int64Dtype())                                                                                          

         number
0  357872400000
1  356837600000
2  353888400000
3           NaN
```

As a shorthand, you may also do,

```
df.astype('float').astype('Int64')                                                                                                 

         number
0  357872400000
1  356837600000
2  353888400000
3           NaN
```

---

On older versions, your only option will be to drop NaNs and convert:

```
df.dropna(subset=['number']).astype({'number':float}).astype({'number':int})                                                        

         number
0  357872400000
1  356837600000
2  353888400000
```